# "more site stats on:" Stack Exchange link does not expand Retrocomputing on the "All Sites" page

Tags: bug, stackexchange

Navigating to Main and clicking on "more site stats on:" -> "stack exchange" should bring me to the All Sites page on Stack Exchange with the Retrocomputing "bubble" expanded.  Instead, it directs me to the list without expanding any sites (http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#).

Is this intentional?  Also, I'm not sure if this should be reported here or on meta.SE.

Comment: This has the [meta-tag:bug] tag, so a Stack Overflow Valued Associate will look at it soon.

Comment: This is still a problem?! Perhaps you should post it on [meta.se]; it seems to be a redirect from `#retrocomputing` to `#`.